# "to carp" vs "to nag"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Could you tell me what the differences between "to carp" and "to nag" are?

I have searched on the internet but still I can't find it out. Perhaps you, native English speakers, can help me.

Answer (score 1):

First, *to nag* is far more common in contemporary English (both American and British, by the look of it).  I can't remember that last time I heard anyone say "carp" other than when they're referring to the fish. There's probably no good reason why you'd ever need to use this word.

But because you've asked:

> **carp**
>
> *intransitive verb*
> : to find fault or complain querulously

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carp

> **nag**
>
> *transitive verb*
> 1 : to irritate by constant scolding or urging
> 2 : badger, worry
>
> *intransitive verb*
> 1 : to find fault incessantly : complain
> 2 : to be a persistent source of annoyance or distraction

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nag

The most obvious (and important) difference is that *carp* has only one meaning, and can only be used intransitively (that means you have to say, "He carped" or "He carped about me" but not "He carped me"), while *nag* has two uses, one intransitive ("He nagged") and one transitive ("He nagged me").

The intransitive use of *nag* is very similar to *carp*. There may be subtle differences between them.

The transitive use of *nag* is different.  When I say, **"He carped all night about the mess in the kitchen"** I mean *he wouldn't stop complaining about the kitchen; he was saying things like, "I can't believe it's so messy.  This kitchen stinks!  What the heck are we going to do about the kitchen?"*

But when I say, **"He nagged me all night about the mess in the kitchen"** it means, *he wouldn't stop telling **me** to clean the kitchen, or complaining **that I hadn't** cleaned the kitchen; he was saying things like, "I can't believe **you** let the kitchen get so messy.  **You** made the kitchen stink.  What the heck are **you** going to do about the kitchen?"*

Comment: I would just add that when directed at a woman, "nag" can have a sexist connotation. I too (American) cannot remember ever hearing someone say "carp".

Comment: *Carp* is alive and well in England. I disagree with Juhasz. Someone who makes a mess in the kitchen needs *nagging*: messy kitchens are way too gross to *carp* about.

Carping is a form of pedantry, but is concerned less with rules than with trivial details: poorly-aligned cutlery on the restaurant table, people saying *'nucular'* instead of *nuclear*, the relative scarcity of *black* Jelly Babies etc.